# finding a particular solution to a differential euqatiion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i'm trying to find the particular solution to a differential equation but i'm not sure i'm approaching this correctly.

i have its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1} = -2$ $\lambda_{2} = -1$ and the eigenvectors are $u = \begin{pmatrix} -0.707107 \\ 0.707107 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix} -0.5547 \\ -0.83205 \end{pmatrix}$.

i think the general solution with arbitrary coefficients is:

$x(t) = -0.707107 \cdot C_{1} \cdot e^{-2t} - 0.5547 \cdot C_{2} \cdot e^{-t}$

$y(t) = 0.707107 \cdot C_{1} \cdot e^{2t} - 0.83205 \cdot C_{2} \cdot e^{-t}$

the initial values of the particular solution are $(x[0], y[0]) = \lambda_{1} + 2 \cdot \lambda_{2} = (-1.81651, -0.956994)$.

i combined the above information with the general solution to solve for $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$.

$x(0) = -1.81651 = -0.707107 \cdot C_{1} - 0.5547 \cdot C_{2} = -1.81651$

$y(0) = 0.707107 \cdot C_{1} - 0.83205 \cdot C_{2} = -0.956994$

$$C_{1} = 4.1376, C_{2} = -2$$

and this allows me to find the particular solution.

$x(t) = -2.925726 \cdot e^{2t} + 1.1094 \cdot e^{-t}$

$y(t) = 2.925726 \cdot e^{-2t} + 1.6641 \cdot e^{-t}$

i approached this question in a way similar to how i've approached a few others, but i'm not sure it is appropriate in this case. any advice? thank you in advance.

Comment: How about writing out a couple of examples? "a differential equation"  covers a lot of ground! :)